# How can I read JSON in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, json, parsing

I need a simple method to read the results from Amazon Affiliates URL, I have the code for Amazon and I get a JSON result which I cannot read in ASP.NET.
Is there an easy method to parse the JSON data in ASP.NET 4.5 ?

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the .NET built-in `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JObject class` based on `Json.net`

Link : http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

For parsing you can use `JObject.Parse Method`

Code

```
   var jsonString = @"{""Name"":""Aghilas"",""Company"":""....."",
                        ""Entered"":""2012-03-16T00:03:33.245-10:00""}";

    dynamic json = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

    // values require casting
    string name = json.Name;
    string company = json.Company;
    DateTime entered = json.Entered;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.NET package, its great and simple.

To install the package:

Open the console. "View" > "Other Windows" > "Package Manager Console"

Then type the following:
**Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**

You can both read the Json object as dynamic object or as strongly-typed one.
In case you want to read the Json type as a strongly typed object, you can do the following:

The class to populate the data:

```
public class AmazonAffiliate
{

public string Username {get;set;}

public string Email {get;set;}

public Date BirthDate {get;set;}

}
```

Method for converting Json strings to strongly-typed class:

```
    public static T GetJsonContent<T>(string jsonAsString)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer<T>();
        return serializer.DeserializeFromString(jsonAsString);
    }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
AmazonAffiliate affiliate = GetJsonContent<AmazonAffiliate>(jsonString);
```